# Get cookie with react

Tags: reactjs, session, cookies, express-session, react-cookie

I need to know if my user is connected or not. For that I want to read the cookies that I set in the server side with express-session :

```js
app.use(session({
    secret: 'crypted key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false } // Put true if https
}))
```

```js
app.post('/connect_user', (req, res) => {
    req.session.cookie.username = req.body.username
    findUserData('username', req.body.username, req, (userData) => {
        req.session.cookie.id = userData.id
        req.session.cookie.username = userData.username
        res.redirect('/profil')
    })
})
```

I tried to use `react-cookie` but it doesn't work even though I copy-pasted the npm `react-cookie` docs example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Landing from './Landing';
import Home from './Home';
import Profil from './Profil';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';

class App extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
      };
     
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     
        const { cookies } = props;
        this.state = {
          username: cookies.get('username')
        };
      }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.name) 
        let homePage = (!this.state.username) ? <Landing/> : <Home/>
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={homePage}></Route>
                    <Route path='/profil' component={Profil}></Route>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

It's weird because `document.cookie` renders the correct result, but I don't know how handle it:

```
PHPSESSID=0nv9ic8h7pv2b63lu4v7eg3mop; user_id=21; username=Ugo; SL_G_WPT_TO=fr; SL_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=undefined; SL_wptGlobTipTmp=undefined
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can use `js-cookie` package and can install it using `npm install js-cookie --save` command.

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

class App extends React.Component {
     this.state = {
        username: Cookies.get('username')
     }

//  more code....
}
```

Documentation  : https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

NPM : https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie

Comment: Why use an additional package if you can do it with Vanilla JS?

Comment: @AndreaD_ because `npm install` is easier than understanding what you're doing

Comment: Therein lies the problem...

Comment: @chaoskreator Why use Vanilla JS if you can do it more simply with an additional package?

Answer (score 32):

If all you want is to get the cookie value by key, I would suggest using plain javascript without any dependencies.

In this example, it gets the cookie value by the key "username" with the help of Regex.

```
let cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)username\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie#Example_2_Get_a_sample_cookie_named_test2

Comment: Why do you suggest not using dependencies when using dependencies is much simpler? What downsides are there for using a dependency in this particular case?

Answer (score 32):

There is no need for a third party npm package. You can use plain JS to extract the cookie. Here is a custom function for that:

```
function getCookie(key) {
  var b = document.cookie.match("(^|;)\\s*" + key + "\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)");
  return b ? b.pop() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I'd recommend using `universal-cookie` as its simpler to use. Mind you, cookies have nothing to do with React. They are stored on the browser and you could use the browser's default API to get cookies.

Here is an example how you can use `universal-cookies`

```
import React from 'react';
// other imports...
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

class App extends React.Component {
     this.state = {
        username: cookies.get('username')
     }

//  more code....
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie

Comment: why do people keep adding this??? `class App extends React.Component {` this is not present in real code

Comment: @uberrebu you don't need `this.state = {`. 

That was just an example of how to use Cookies`.

Instead of `this.state`, you can do: `const myCookieData = cookies.get('username')`

Comment: @uberrebu it was in 2018 when the answer was written. That's the way components where declared before functional components and hooks where commonplace

Comment: @uberrebu looks like your standard class component to me...

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the method below without any 3rd party package as documented in [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie#example_2_get_a_sample_cookie_named_test2) :

```js
const cookieValue = document.cookie
  .split('; ')
  .find((row) => row.startsWith('YOUR-COOKIE='))?
  .split('=')[1];
```

Comment: A better version that doesn't trigger any exception, and instead returns `undefined` if the cookie doesn't exist: `document.cookie.split('; ').filter(row => row.startsWith('cookie_name=')).map(c=>c.split('=')[1])[0]`

Answer (score 8):

If you have a cookie with "httpOnly:true" property, you can't access it with document.cookie. It might be the reason you have failed to access the cookie with these methods.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this function may help:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cookie = key=>((new RegExp((key || '=')+'=(.*?); ','gm')).exec(document.cookie+'; ') ||['',null])[1]
console.log(cookie('test'))
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 