# How to read cookies with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, js-cookie, react-cookie

I have a cookie on my browser and I want to read it with react, I use it like that:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
console.log(Cookies.get('cookieName1'));
```

when I run it, I get `undefined` on the console, but, the cookieName1 have a value on my cookies.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: can your print just `Cookies.get();` and show us what you see there...?

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is visible to JavaScript? A cookie set by a server can be marked as `HttpOnly` which means that it is not visible from JavaScript

Comment: Can you run  ```console.log(document.cookie)``` and tell us what you get.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it return `undefined`

Comment: @Mark it return `undefined`

Comment: @NineBerry how can I make it visible to Javascript ?

Comment: @CodeLover You can't.. It is for security reasons..

Comment: @ArupRakshit so I can't access to cookies ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have cookies.  When on the site you think you have cookies for go to your developer tools, the application tab and then under storage check the 'Cookies' tab.  Is there anything in there?

Comment: @Mark, yes I have a cookies

Comment: @CodeLover Show us what you see there in developer tools. All the properties of the cookies

Comment: @NineBerry I have used js-cookies like the answer and it works well, thank you.

Comment: Get cookie by using document.cookie  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707172/1604503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used js-cookies which works well.

```
import cookies from "js-cookies";

const secure = window.location.protocol === 'https'
```

to set value in cookie use below code

```
cookies.setItem("API_TOKEN", "hello", undefined, "/", undefined, secure)
```

to get value from cookie use below code

```
cookies.getItem("API_TOKEN")
```

to remove cookie use below code

```
cookies.removeItem('API_TOKEN')
```

Comment: js-cookie 3.0.1 uses get instead of getItem.

Answer (score 1):

if a cookie is marked as HttpOnly, it is not accessible on the client-side using JavaScript. The HttpOnly flag is a security feature for cookies that restricts them from being accessed by client-side scripts. This is done to mitigate the risk of cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, where an attacker injects malicious scripts into a website, and those scripts attempt to steal sensitive information, such as cookies.