# Read cookie data with NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js

On my NextJS site I created authentication cookies to have the data on any page.

my code :

```
  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [
    serialize("access_token", access_token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
      sameSite: "lax",
      path: "/",
    }),
    serialize("token_type", token_type, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
      sameSite: "lax",
      path: "/",
    }),
  ]);
```

However, I would like, in another page, to retrieve cookie data (read cookies) to display them on my page.

How I can do that ?

Comment: you can keep this data in localstorage also.
plus you look answer here for react reading cooking 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479576/how-to-read-cookies-with-react

Comment: when I try to do `cookies.setItem ("API_TOKEN", "hello", undefined, "/", undefined, "https");` it tells me that `document is not defined` pointing to the module

Comment: And if not, would you have another solution?

Comment: Move your cookies access inside a `useEffect` on the client-side code. Also, bear in mind that setting [`httpOnly: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) on the cookie will make it inaccessible to JavaScript code on the client.

Comment: ok but after the `useEffect` how do I get the value because? Do you have an example?